# Using Thread.new vs a Background Worker like Resque in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, resque

For long running processes like mailing and posting to external sites, is it ok to use the Ruby Thread.new instead of a background worker like Delayed Jobs or Resque?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by OK.  Ruby has a Global Interpreter Lock (most implementations do anyway - JRuby is one exception) which means you will not get true concurrency using the Thread.new method.  That doesn't mean you aren't getting any concurrency at all though.  This is discussed in more depth in multiple places:

- http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/02/06/the-ruby-global-interpreter-lock/
- http://merbist.com/2011/10/03/about-concurrency-and-the-gil/
- http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/

The Delayed Jobs and Resque methods both involve having one or more separate processes performing the long running operation(s).  With multiple processes you will have true concurrency between your rails app and the background worker process(es) since the GIL does not get in the way at all.